# How to convert a rectangle of cells to a row/column of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dataset from range A1:T25 and I want this to be in a single row or column. There are 25 rows and 20 columns. I tried the following:

```
={A1:A25; B1:B25; C1:C25; D1:D25; E1:E25; F1:F25; G1:G5; H1:H25; I1:I25; J1:J25; K1:K25; L1:L25; M1:M25; N1:N25; O1:O25; P1:P25; Q1:Q25; R1:R25; S1:S25; T1:T25}
```

After pressing `Enter` a column appears with my data, but somehow there are 480 cells instead of the 500. I want to know which of the multiple ranges I made a mistake in, as well as a ***short, non-repetitive*** way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an alternative would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:T25), , 10000))), " ")))
```

[image: 0]

or for the row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:T25), , 10000))), " "))
```

or column by column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", 
 QUERY(A1:T25, , 10000)), " ")))
```

or column by column in the row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", 
 QUERY(A1:T25, , 10000)), " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an update, with credit to Matt King and new in 2020, the `FLATTEN` function does precisely this.  It is undocumented, but you can now find many examples on SO.

```
=FLATTEN(A1:T25)
```

gives a one column version of all the data cells in the range.

Answer (score 0):

mistake spotted at **`G1:G5`**

try:

```
={A1:A25; B1:B25; C1:C25; D1:D25; E1:E25; 
  F1:F25; G1:G25; H1:H25; I1:I25; J1:J25; 
  K1:K25; L1:L25; M1:M25; N1:N25; O1:O25; 
  P1:P25; Q1:Q25; R1:R25; S1:S25; T1:T25}
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way? I will get tired of doing this again in another sheet if I have to.