# Chart showing amount of numbers in dataset in Google Sheets

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of 500 numbers (range A1:T25) from 1-200 that I need to put in a pie chart showing the popularity of each number from 1-200. When I try to select all of the cells and put them in a pie chart, I can see multiple slices for each number. I even tried [putting the cells into a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327174/how-to-convert-a-rectangle-of-cells-to-a-row-column-of-cells-in-google-sheets).

Comment: Both answers worked, but the pie charts are most definitely **ugly**!

Comment: maybe you could drop less popular ones like 1-5

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use a chart for popularity. I already have 4 charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", 
 QUERY(A1:T25, , 10000)), " "))),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"),
 "order by Col2 desc")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The formula also shows the numbers in order from most popular to least popular. The mode (199) is at the top, with 15 instances.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your data is not uniformly distributed—pie charts with 200 slices can be hideous!

If I'm understanding your goal correctly, you don't actually want a chart of those 500 numbers, you want a chart of how often each value appears in that set. Generate a report of *that* data in pairs, and chart that.

For example in a cell with 200 empty cells below it, say A30 or V1, enter:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(1:200))`
These are your possible values, 1 to 200.

Then next to it in say, B30 or W1, enter:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF($A$1:$T$25, "="&ROW(1:200)))`
These are individual counts of how often each A column number appears in A1:T25.

Now that your values and their 'popularity' counted out, create your pie chart from that.

Comment: In fact, these 500 numbers are "random" numbers given to me by 25 people (20 each), but they are not uniformly distributed. The mode is 199.